# "Why is your corporate mentorship program successful?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

In regards to the question ["Why is your corporate mentorship program successful?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84822/why-is-your-corporate-mentorship-program-successful), the author seems to be receptive to feedback and wants to try to make their question on-topic. I'd love to get this reopened for them, but I'm not sure how to improve it.

Can anyone else see a way to improve this question so it can be reopened?

Comment: I certainly appreciate the OP's efforts. However, as it currently stands, the question is not suited to SE. Sorry to be blunt, but OP is essentially asking how to do his job based on how others do a similar job.

Comment: It's too broad right now, but breaking it down into subtasks might help.  What are his specific goals?  Is he looking for ways to get busy people to spend X hours a week being mentors?  Is he trying to optimize matchmaking?  Is he trying to identify important topics that mentors should explicitly try to teach?  Is he trying to figure out how to make mentoring a regular part of daily activities?  Questions like those would be better fits.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I definitely agree with you, though I don't think the OP is understanding that distinction. I don't think it's ready to reopen yet, but somehow there are three votes already.

Comment: "What makes a...." would be an improvement, though still too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Change the question to:

We are creating a corporate mentorship program:

We have concerns about these issues: ... 
We want to achieve these things: ...
We have the ability to offer these incentives: ...

How can we best implement this program?